# How to create Infowindows for multiple markers with drop animation

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have successfully coded to drop multiple markers at certain interval and also know how to create multiple infowindows without drop animation.But, I dont know how to create infowindows for multiple markers with drop animation.I need both in one and I am struggling with this as i am new to javascript.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds ();
    var berlin = new google.maps.LatLng(13.00843, 80.21215);

    var neighborhoods = [ new google.maps.LatLng(13.00843, 80.21215),
     new google.maps.LatLng(13.00881, 80.21143),
     new google.maps.LatLng(13.00861, 80.21085),
     new google.maps.LatLng(13.00859, 80.21085),
     new google.maps.LatLng(13.00859, 80.21085),
     new google.maps.LatLng(13.00859, 80.21085),
     new google.maps.LatLng(13.00859, 80.21085),
     new google.maps.LatLng(13.00859, 80.21085),
     new google.maps.LatLng(13.00859, 80.21085),
     new google.maps.LatLng(13.00859, 80.21085),
     new google.maps.LatLng(13.00859, 80.21085),
     new google.maps.LatLng(13.00859, 80.21085),
     new google.maps.LatLng(13.00859, 80.21085),
     new google.maps.LatLng(13.00859, 80.21085),
     new google.maps.LatLng(13.00859, 80.21085),
     new google.maps.LatLng(13.00859, 80.21085),
     new google.maps.LatLng(13.00856, 80.21071),
     new google.maps.LatLng(13.00856, 80.21053),
     new google.maps.LatLng(13.00843, 80.21023),
     new google.maps.LatLng(13.00838, 80.20999),
     new google.maps.LatLng(13.00804, 80.20887),
     new google.maps.LatLng(13.00777, 80.207),
     new google.maps.LatLng(13.0076, 80.20554),
     new google.maps.LatLng(13.00701, 80.20469),
     new google.maps.LatLng(13.00532, 80.20192),
     new google.maps.LatLng(13.00388, 80.20111),
     new google.maps.LatLng(13.00238, 80.2005),
     new google.maps.LatLng(13.00189, 80.19991),
     new google.maps.LatLng(13.00192, 80.19675),
     new google.maps.LatLng(13.00011, 80.19431),
     new google.maps.LatLng(12.99835, 80.19217),
     new google.maps.LatLng(12.99555, 80.18887),
     new google.maps.LatLng(12.9911, 80.18111),
     new google.maps.LatLng(12.9874, 80.17626),
     new google.maps.LatLng(12.98264, 80.16883),
     new google.maps.LatLng(12.97428, 80.15462),
     new google.maps.LatLng(12.96853, 80.14983),
     new google.maps.LatLng(12.96691, 80.149),
     new google.maps.LatLng(12.9623, 80.14663),
     new google.maps.LatLng(12.96064, 80.14581),
     new google.maps.LatLng(12.95152, 80.14029),
     new google.maps.LatLng(12.94606, 80.13628),
     new google.maps.LatLng(12.93716, 80.12813),
     new google.maps.LatLng(12.92727, 80.11845),
     new google.maps.LatLng(12.92727, 80.11845),
     new google.maps.LatLng(12.92727, 80.11845),
     new google.maps.LatLng(12.92727, 80.11845),
     new google.maps.LatLng(12.92727, 80.11845),
     new google.maps.LatLng(12.91545, 80.1045),
     new google.maps.LatLng(12.90816, 80.09801),
     new google.maps.LatLng(12.88163, 80.08141),
     new google.maps.LatLng(12.86243, 80.07368),
     new google.maps.LatLng(12.85883, 80.07145),
     new google.maps.LatLng(12.83887, 80.05463),
     new google.maps.LatLng(12.81113, 80.03094),
     new google.maps.LatLng(12.78636, 80.01549),
     new google.maps.LatLng(12.75723, 80.00227),
     new google.maps.LatLng(12.73914, 79.99043),
     new google.maps.LatLng(12.69862, 79.96948),
     new google.maps.LatLng(12.66697, 79.95867),
     new google.maps.LatLng(12.62878, 79.93155),
     new google.maps.LatLng(12.5874, 79.9173),
     new google.maps.LatLng(12.55993, 79.91112),
     new google.maps.LatLng(12.51569, 79.89052),
     new google.maps.LatLng(12.48418, 79.86374),
     new google.maps.LatLng(12.45468, 79.84108),
     new google.maps.LatLng(12.4354, 79.83541),
     new google.maps.LatLng(12.40707, 79.82117),
     new google.maps.LatLng(12.38243, 79.79353),
     new google.maps.LatLng(12.36767, 79.7822),
     new google.maps.LatLng(12.32709, 79.77705),
     new google.maps.LatLng(12.30646, 79.75113),
     new google.maps.LatLng(12.28969, 79.7216),
     new google.maps.LatLng(12.27879, 79.7077),
     new google.maps.LatLng(12.26285, 79.68298),
     new google.maps.LatLng(12.25832, 79.67903),
     new google.maps.LatLng(12.91417, 80.22938),
     new google.maps.LatLng(12.923964, 80.12469),
     new google.maps.LatLng(12.8791617, 80.18394),
     new google.maps.LatLng(13.00843, 80.21215),
     new google.maps.LatLng(13.00843, 80.21215)];



    var markers = [];
    var iterator = 0;

    var map;
    function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 10,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      center: berlin
    };


    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
            mapOptions);
    setMarkers(map, neighbourhoods);


    }

    function drop() {
    for (var i = 0; i < neighborhoods.length; i++) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        addMarker();
      }, i * 1000);


        }
    }



    var image = 'images/car_icon_small.png';
    function addMarker() {
    var marker=markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
      position: neighborhoods[iterator],
      map: map,
      draggable: false,
    icon: image,
    title: neighborhoodsName[iterator],
      animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
    }));

    iterator++;
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Can you post the code,where you were trying 'to create multiple infowindows'.

Answer (score 1):

After a long try,i solved my problem. here is what i did:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds ();
var berlin = new google.maps.LatLng(13.00843, 80.21215);

var neighborhoods = [ new google.maps.LatLng(13.00843, 80.21215),
 new google.maps.LatLng(13.00881, 80.21143),
 new google.maps.LatLng(13.00861, 80.21085),
 new google.maps.LatLng(13.00859, 80.21085),
 new google.maps.LatLng(13.00859, 80.21085),
 new google.maps.LatLng(13.00859, 80.21085),
 new google.maps.LatLng(13.00859, 80.21085),
 new google.maps.LatLng(13.00859, 80.21085),
 new google.maps.LatLng(13.00859, 80.21085),
 new google.maps.LatLng(13.00859, 80.21085),
 new google.maps.LatLng(13.00859, 80.21085),
 new google.maps.LatLng(13.00859, 80.21085),
 new google.maps.LatLng(13.00859, 80.21085),
 new google.maps.LatLng(13.00859, 80.21085),
 new google.maps.LatLng(13.00859, 80.21085),
 new google.maps.LatLng(13.00859, 80.21085),
 new google.maps.LatLng(13.00856, 80.21071),
 new google.maps.LatLng(13.00856, 80.21053),
 new google.maps.LatLng(13.00843, 80.21023),
 new google.maps.LatLng(13.00838, 80.20999),
 new google.maps.LatLng(13.00804, 80.20887),
 new google.maps.LatLng(13.00777, 80.207),
 new google.maps.LatLng(13.0076, 80.20554),
 new google.maps.LatLng(13.00701, 80.20469),
 new google.maps.LatLng(13.00532, 80.20192),
 new google.maps.LatLng(13.00388, 80.20111),
 new google.maps.LatLng(13.00238, 80.2005),
 new google.maps.LatLng(13.00189, 80.19991),
 new google.maps.LatLng(13.00192, 80.19675),
 new google.maps.LatLng(13.00011, 80.19431),
 new google.maps.LatLng(12.99835, 80.19217),
 new google.maps.LatLng(12.99555, 80.18887),
 new google.maps.LatLng(12.9911, 80.18111),
 new google.maps.LatLng(12.9874, 80.17626),
 new google.maps.LatLng(12.98264, 80.16883),
 new google.maps.LatLng(12.97428, 80.15462),
 new google.maps.LatLng(12.96853, 80.14983),
 new google.maps.LatLng(12.96691, 80.149),
 new google.maps.LatLng(12.9623, 80.14663),
 new google.maps.LatLng(12.96064, 80.14581),
 new google.maps.LatLng(12.95152, 80.14029),
 new google.maps.LatLng(12.94606, 80.13628),
 new google.maps.LatLng(12.93716, 80.12813),
 new google.maps.LatLng(12.92727, 80.11845),
 new google.maps.LatLng(12.92727, 80.11845),
 new google.maps.LatLng(12.92727, 80.11845),
 new google.maps.LatLng(12.92727, 80.11845),
 new google.maps.LatLng(12.92727, 80.11845),
 new google.maps.LatLng(12.91545, 80.1045),
 new google.maps.LatLng(12.90816, 80.09801),
 new google.maps.LatLng(12.88163, 80.08141),
 new google.maps.LatLng(12.86243, 80.07368),
 new google.maps.LatLng(12.85883, 80.07145),
 new google.maps.LatLng(12.83887, 80.05463),
 new google.maps.LatLng(12.81113, 80.03094),
 new google.maps.LatLng(12.78636, 80.01549),
 new google.maps.LatLng(12.75723, 80.00227),
 new google.maps.LatLng(12.73914, 79.99043),
 new google.maps.LatLng(12.69862, 79.96948),
 new google.maps.LatLng(12.66697, 79.95867),
 new google.maps.LatLng(12.62878, 79.93155),
 new google.maps.LatLng(12.5874, 79.9173),
 new google.maps.LatLng(12.55993, 79.91112),
 new google.maps.LatLng(12.51569, 79.89052),
 new google.maps.LatLng(12.48418, 79.86374),
 new google.maps.LatLng(12.45468, 79.84108),
 new google.maps.LatLng(12.4354, 79.83541),
 new google.maps.LatLng(12.40707, 79.82117),
 new google.maps.LatLng(12.38243, 79.79353),
 new google.maps.LatLng(12.36767, 79.7822),
 new google.maps.LatLng(12.32709, 79.77705),
 new google.maps.LatLng(12.30646, 79.75113),
 new google.maps.LatLng(12.28969, 79.7216),
 new google.maps.LatLng(12.27879, 79.7077),
 new google.maps.LatLng(12.26285, 79.68298),
 new google.maps.LatLng(12.25832, 79.67903),
 new google.maps.LatLng(12.91417, 80.22938),
 new google.maps.LatLng(12.923964, 80.12469),
 new google.maps.LatLng(12.8791617, 80.18394),
 new google.maps.LatLng(13.00843, 80.21215),
 new google.maps.LatLng(13.00843, 80.21215)];



var markers = [];
var iterator = 0;

var map;
function initialize() {
var mapOptions = {
  zoom: 10,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
  center: berlin
};


map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
        mapOptions);
setMarkers(map, neighbourhoods);


}

function drop() {
for (var i = 0; i < neighborhoods.length; i++) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    addMarker();
  }, i * 1000);


    }
}



var image = 'images/car_icon_small.png';
function addMarker() {
var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
  position: neighborhoods[iterator],
  map: map,
  draggable: false,
icon: image,
title: neighborhoodsName[iterator],
  animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
});
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content:'Hello World'
      });


      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
      });
     markers.push(marker);

iterator++;
}


</script>
```

thanks a lot.

One more thing.When markers drop beyond currently set map area,i want the map to move in order to show the marker.How to do this with this code??